# How to remove these red lines and word in microsoft word?

Tags: microsoft-word

I am using

- Windows 10
- 64 bit
- Microsoft office 2013

Problem: When I start working in word these red line start appearing.

- What are these ?

[image: screenshot]

- How can I remove them?

**What have I tried?**

- https://technadvice.com/eliminate-red-lines-in-word/

Comment: The suggestions from the link you posted should work. Close and re-open Word, check if the issue persists.

Comment: This article says these red line for spelling mistakes. See my screenshot these are different type of red lines. @ReddyLutonadio

Comment: Lines around "Formatted: Centered"?

Comment: yes @ReddyLutonadio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Track changes and Show comments are enabled in your document.

- Go to Review,
- Click on "Show Comments" to stop showing the comments.

If you also want to want to see the changes made on the document, set Tracking to "No Markup".

Comment: These were comments. I just opened microsoft word. How did these comment were enabled? I just wrote some text. and then I pressed Ctrl + E to center align it. It started showing these comments. Thanks for answering my question. I really appreciate it.

Comment: I guess you must have enable tracking changes by mistake by pressing Ctrl + Shift + E.

Comment: Comments are always "enabled." It is the viewing that can be switched on and off. You can delete comments as well.